# Twitter Bootstrap, collapse menu and submenu managing events

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, events

please help me with:

I have this collapse menu and submenu:

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <div class="level1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            My Interests <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right img-panel-1"></i>
        </div>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="sub-menus">
            <div class="panel-1-1" href="#sub1" data-toggle="collapse">
                MY MOVIES <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right img-panel_1_1"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="sub1">
                <a href="#">
                    Action 
                </a>
                <hr>
                <a href="#">
                     dventure 
                </a>
                <hr>
                <a href="#">
                    Add / Remove 
                </a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="panel-1-2" href="#sub2" data-toggle="collapse">
                MY CHANNELS <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right img-panel_1_2"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="sub2">
                <a href="#">
                    80's Rock 
                </a>
                <hr>
                <a href="#">
                   Hip Hop 
                </a>
                <hr>
                <a href="#">
                    Add / Remove 
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm using these events to change the arrow image of link (collapse item) clicked:

```
$('.panel-1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.img-panel-1').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
$('.panel-1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.img-panel-1').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
$('#collapseOne').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.img-panel_1_1').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
$('#collapseOne').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.img-panel_1_1').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
$('#collapseOne').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.img-panel_1_2').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
$('#collapseOne').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.img-panel_1_2').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
```

But when I click on any link (collapse item) all images changes, the event is applied to menu and submenu at same time, I need that the image changes only at menu if this is clicked or submenu if this is clicked only.

[Here you can see what happen with this arrows](http://www.codeply.com/go/72YXPAaBDI)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,answering my own question:

Is necessary assign to each **panel-group** class a different **id** and relate it to child attribute **data-parent**, this solved the issue raised.

[Here](http://www.codeply.com/go/qohm7U3XOu) you can see the code works fantastic ;)